# How to listen to the event(commit event) in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We set up a fabric server, and put some transaction into it. And we have some applications those will cooperate with the fabric server. Here is a situation.

- Application send a transaction with `fabric-sdk-java` or `fabric-sdk-node`
- The fabric excute the `chaincode`
- The fabric notify the application about the result / The application listen to the event of the transaction (commit transaction, generate blockchain, append the blockchain, update the world state, etc.)
- Application notify the custom about the transaction result.

As you know, the excution of the `chaincode` would cost some time. Especially, the `blockchain` would be commit after tens of seconds. So I want the `peer` callback a `url` or just let the application know the result of the execution. Is is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register to even hub and listed for notifications of block/transaction being committed. If you are looking for example please consider to take a look at [fabcar](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/fabcar) from [fabric-samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples). In particular you might want to take a look on [invoke.js](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/fabcar/invoke.js).

```
var options = {
    wallet_path: path.join(__dirname, './creds'),
    user_id: 'PeerAdmin',
    channel_id: 'mychannel',
    chaincode_id: 'fabcar',
    peer_url: 'grpc://localhost:7051',
    event_url: 'grpc://localhost:7053',
    orderer_url: 'grpc://localhost:7050'
};



    let eh = client.newEventHub();
    eh.setPeerAddr(options.event_url);
    eh.connect();


    let txPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let handle = setTimeout(() => {
            eh.disconnect();
            reject();
        }, 30000);

        eh.registerTxEvent(transactionID, (tx, code) => {
            clearTimeout(handle);
            eh.unregisterTxEvent(transactionID);
            eh.disconnect();

            if (code !== 'VALID') {
                console.error(
                    'The transaction was invalid, code = ' + code);
                reject();
            } else {
                console.log(
                    'The transaction has been committed on peer ' +
                    eh._ep._endpoint.addr);
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
    eventPromises.push(txPromise);
```

Similar API exists also in Java and Golang SDKs.

Comment: I believe this is an outdated solution as events are now channel based

Answer (score -5):

Hyperledger Composer has changed how we work with the Hyperledger Fabric Blockchain. Although I cannot give you all the introductions here I provide you a snippet of code on how ([credits to](https://medium.com/@alex.cs1/hyperledger-from-scratch-part-2-4bc6f45180f8)):

1. To define an event
2. Emit an event from your transaction
3. Listen to events from your application

1) Defining an event: here I have an event that consists a doctor, a patient, and a message.

```
    event MedicalEvent {
    --> Doctor thedoctor
    --> Patient thePatient
    o String theMessage
    }
    transaction sampleTransaction {
    --> Doctor thedoctor
    --> Patient thePatient
    }
```

2) Emitting an event from a transaction: here we will have the logic of the Chain code.

```
    /**
     *@ALL NECCESSARY DECORATIONS GO HERE
     /
    sampleTransaction(obj) {
    var factory = getFactory();
    var patient = obj.thepatient;
    var doctor = obj.thedoctor;
    var message = 'Take your medications PROPERLY';

    return getParticipantRegistry('org.acme.WHATEVER.Patient')
    .then(function(patientRegistry) {
       var basicEvent = factory.newEvent('org.acme.WHATEVER', 'addMeLiveEvent');
       basicEvent.theDoctor=doctor;
       basicEvent.thePatient=patient;
       basicEvent.theMessage = message;
       emit(basicEvent);
     })
    }
```

3) Listen to events: here I have my Nodejs listening to events.

```
    const BusinessNetworkConnection = require('composer-client').BusinessNetworkConnection;
    this.bizNetworkConnection = new BusinessNetworkConnection();
    this.cardName ='admin@YOUR-NETWORK';
    this.businessNetworkIdentifier = 'YOUR-NETWORK';

    this.bizNetworkConnection.connect(this.cardName)
    .then((result) => { 
    //You can do ANYTHING
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    throw error;
    });


    this.bizNetworkConnection.on('event',(evt)=>{
     console.log('Amount Transfered: '+evt.theMessage);
    });
```

Comment: The question is about fabric, not composer